# Installing XCode from a USB (or similar workarounds)

Tags: usb, install, xcode

I initially posted this on Stack Overflow, but I think this might be the better place for it. I'm trying to install XCode on an old Mac with about 40GB of space, which isn't enough to install XCode (the install needs about 35, and the .xip file takes up 10). My latest idea was to put the .xip file on an external USB and install from there, but it doesn't seem to be working - it throws a "Directory not found" error at the end of the "Expanding" process.

I don't have enough experience with MacOS to work out how I should be troubleshooting this, or even to figure out what directory this is talking about. Is there a way to do this that would actually work? I'd ideally have liked to install XCode on this external drive and run it from there, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159232/can-i-install-xcode-on-an-external-hard-drive-along-with-the-iphone-simulator-ap) seems to suggest that it's not possible with the more recent versions.